# Расширенное фиксированное или прилипающее(sticky) позиционирование flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, position

Есть готовая верстка(angular проект) на flexbox-е, оно состоит из левого меню, контента и sidebar-a.

Контент меняется динамически и у него может быть своё меню.
В моем случае в контенте есть меню и панель действий и дальше идет длинный список.

Нужно как то сделать фиксированным левое меню, меню и панель действий контента.
Я добавил position sticky но почему-то левое меню уходит с половины скролла, также меню контента скрывает тень нижнего блока.

Я бы мог полностью пересмотреть структуру верстки, но не могу так как это уже работающий проект и данное решение нужно только для одной динамической страницы.

Спасибо.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  max-width: 980px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}
.content header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
.content header ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content header ul li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.content .main-box {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.content .main-box .action-panel {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 70px;
  background: #fff;
}
.content .main-box .list-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 170px);
}
.content .main-box .list-container .list-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <aside>
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Должна быть фикривонной при скроле</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Левое меню</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Левое меню</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Должна быть фикривонной при скроле</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>

  <div class="content">
    <!--
    here goes dynamic content
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  -->

    <header>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Должна быть фикривонной при скроле</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Меня динамического контента</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>

    <section class="main-box">
      <div class="action-panel">
        <p>Панель действий должна быть фиксированной при скроле</p>
        <button type="button">Действие</button>
      </div>
      <div class="list-container">
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
        <div class="list-item">Список</div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      copyright 2019
    </footer>

  </div>

  <aside></aside>
</main>
```

Comment: скриншот сделайте как дополнение а код поместите в сниппет stackoverflow если действительно хотите что бы вам помогли

Comment: @MaximLensky вставил код как snippet.

Comment: а js не рассматриваете как вариант решения ?

Comment: @MaximLensky я не нашел, макет в такой структуре и только в одной динамической странице они должны быть фиксированным.

Comment: Сейчас работает sticky и то не правильно при половине скролл-а все это уходит на верх.

Comment: вот смотрите, я делал уже такое : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pXYNPw

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо, наверное должно помочь.